# Is it accessible when I wrap the header in a link?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a header and I would like to create a back to homepage link from it. Is it a mistake if I do this?

```
<a href="index.php?menuid=1" title="Go back to the homepage.">
   <header>
       <h1>Title of the page</h1>
   </header>
</a>
```

If it's better to create link from the `<h1>` then how to expand the link to the size of the header? Because the link on it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Semantically, it is incorrect; Your link is your link and your header is your header.  Technically speaking, I don't see why not (bear in mind the clickable area will be the entire `<header>` tag (all width and length of it) which may be something you want (or not)

Comment: You can always add CSS to to expand the clickable area like this: `h1 a{ display: block; width: 100%; }`

Comment: I would love to see proof that this is valid HTML, besides the validator, which is buggy. You're wrapping an inline container `a` around two block levels. `h1` and `header` are `width:100%` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the entire header to be a link, that is the correct way to do it (at least in modern HTML5 browsers).  If you want your `<h1>` to be the full width of `<header>` then add

```
h1 {
  width: 100%
}
```

to your CSS (though you should add an id or class to the h1 and select through that, better than a general `h1`).

Comment: @darksoul90 Exactly what I said would happen, happened.  The h1 takes up the full width of header

Comment: How to do this with the height too?

Comment: Add `height: 100%` to the CSS?

Comment: According to my jsfiddle example - nothing happens

Comment: That's my fault. I mixed blurfus' and your answer. You're right, thank you.

Comment: @darksoul90 No hurt feelings, glad I could help.  Don't forget to upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer for what is worth (also updated you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7JPB/3/))

```
header{
    display:block;
    height:210px;
    width:560px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#eb4172;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
}
h1 {
    background-color:#00aaff;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}

h1 a{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```